# Stream que lê byte por byte?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, revisão-de-código

Eu criei um simples método que lê byte-por-byte num stream, mas ele está muito lento e está demorando minutos para processar um arquivo de dez megabytes, eu não sei o porquê de estar tão lento. Ele precisa ser byte-por-byte e não `byte[]` porque é uma operação que faço num único `byte` numa determinada posição e escreve o mesmo na mesma posição do stream. O código da *gambiarra*:

```
public void EncryptStream(Stream s) {

    // verificações
    if (s == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("s", "Stream cannot be nothing.");
    if (s.CanRead == false) throw new Exception("Stream is not readable.");
    if (s.CanWrite == false) throw new Exception("Stream is not writeable.");

    long len = s.Length;
    for(long i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        s.Position = i;
        // "a" é o byte que está sendo operacionado no stream
        // "i" é a posição que o byte está no stream
        // o byte "a" será escrito novamente na mesma posição após a
        // operação abaixo.
        int a = s.ReadByte(); s.Position--;
        int pos = computePos(key, i);
        a += pos;
        s.WriteByte((byte)a);
    }
    byte checksun = performKeyHash(key);
    Console.WriteLine("CheckE = " + checksun.ToString());
    s.Position = len + 1;
    s.WriteByte(checksun);
    s.Close();
}
```

O que está errado para estar tão lento? Há algo que possa ser feito? **Lembrando que não posso fazer com que o Stream leia um buffer de byte, precisa ser byte-por-byte**.

Comment: A resposta está na pergunta, se quer criar uma restrição artificial conviva com o problema que ela causa.

Comment: Não há uma outra maneira "mais correta" de refazer isso?

Comment: Tem várias coisas que precisaria analisar. Precisa ser `Stream`? realmente precisa ser genérico? Não pode fazer versões diferente para cada tipo de `Stream` justo para sua própria necessidade? Tem algum que provavelmente será mais usado? Tem algumas variáveis e funções que não sei pra que servem. Sabe onde está o gargalo? Tem que mexer nele. Tem que fazer ajustes e testar. Dá pra consertar uma quantidade de grande de problemas deste código, mas a performance depende de coisas que eu não sei pelo que está postado.